# Atom portable - python not found

Tags: python, atom-editor, unc

I have atom portable in a local folder, however python and my project are on a networked drive. Atom gives me the error:

**(Networked directory)**

**CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

How would I make it so that it can find python?

Comment: can you install python locally?

Comment: create an variable enviroment path for python then recheck it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer which worked for me was just to create a bat file in the directory within which I wished to open atom. The bat file was:

```
setlocal
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python33
"...\AtomPortable\App\Atom\atom.exe"
endlocal
```